# release failure should trigger Incident

Tags: azure, azure-devops

In Azure Devops when a release is pushed and if it gets failed due to any reason it should trigger ICM incident (monitoring alert - MDM) indicating that particular release failure.

Comment: did you ever find a way to generate an ICM incident from a ADO release failure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default feature **Notifications** of Azure Devops to send an email notification to team members after the compilation fails. There is an option `Deployment to an owned stage failed`, you can check if it meets your requirement, if not, you can also set you custom notification.

Check following document for some more details:

https://edi.wang/post/2019/2/21/send-email-after-release-deployment-in-azure-devops

Besides, there is a extension Create Bug on Release failure:

Get it from: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmanBedi18.CreateBugTask

Which you can use it to create a bug (work item) in current or custom defined area & iteration path for the team project in VSTS on release failure with details like repro steps, errors, description, title, priority, severity & assigns it to the person who triggered the release.

Note: Ensure that "Run this task" setting for the task is set to "Only when a previous task has failed". This enables the task able to get error logs from all the tasks in the release pipeline which have failed in the current environment.

Hope this helps.